# Unknown syntax error in HCS08 MCU

Tags: c, microcontroller

I'm programming a freescale MCU and I'm using codewarrior version 10.5. I just downloaded some code from the distributor's web page, and I'm getting this syntax error in the next lines. Any help wold be appreciated!

```
/* Initialization of the CPU registers in FLASH */

/* NVPROT: FPS=0x7F,FPDIS=1 */
const volatile NVPROTSTR _NVPROT @0x0000FFBD = { 0xFF };

/* NVOPT: KEYEN=0,FNORED=1,SEC01=1,SEC00=0 */
const volatile NVOPTSTR _NVOPT @0x0000FFBF = { 0x7E };
```

Also I don't understand the use of `@` here. Is it any special register? Is it an address?

This is what I get in the console:

```
**** Build of configuration FLASH for project qg8_test ****

"C:\\Freescale\\CW MCU v10.5\\gnu\\bin\\mingw32-make" -j8 all 
'Building file: ../Sources/MCUinit.c'
'Executing target #1 ../Sources/MCUinit.c'
'Invoking: HCS08 Compiler'
"C:/Freescale/CW MCU v10.5/MCU/prog/chc08" -ArgFile"Sources/MCUinit.args" -ObjN="Sources/MCUinit_c.obj" "../Sources/MCUinit.c" -Lm="Sources/MCUinit_c.d" -LmCfg=xilmou
../Sources/MCUinit.c
Command Line: '-ArgFile"Sources/MCUinit.args" -ObjN="Sources/MCUinit_c.obj" "../Sources/MCUinit.c" -Lm="Sources/MCUinit_c.d" -LmCfg=xilmou'
C:/Users/oskra/workspace/qg8_test/Project_Headers\../Sources\MCUinit.c
 C:/Users/oskra/workspace/qg8_test/Project_Headers\MC9S08QG8.h
Option -Lm Update: Create new dependency file
Option -Lm: Adding make info to 'Sources/MCUinit_c.d'
C:/Users/oskra/workspace/qg8_test/Project_Headers\../Sources\MCUinit.c:135:error:C2450 Expected:  ~ ( IDENT
mingw32-make: *** [Sources/MCUinit_c.obj] Error 1
```

Comment: And where exactly is the syntax error? Could you please post it? I've personally never seen `@` before a number in C, this might a compiler extension.

Comment: Are you sure that's standard C code and not some variant or something that requires a custom pre-processor?

Comment: This notation is a Code Warrior HCS08 extension for locating variables at an absolute address. In this case encoding a few fuse bytes at magic addresses of FLASH which the MCU interprets as security and start-up options. Anyway, as mentioned the actual error would be highly relevant here. Nevertheless, does it compile with the '@' operator and address portion removed? Conversely does it compile if you omit the types and substitute plain character types and literal initialization in place of the brackets?